# How do I minimize the size of a Flutter Web Release?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

My web folder after building my Flutter Web app comes to 15.4MB which isn't too bad, but I might as well optimize.

I was wondering if anybody has any tips outside the obvious(removing unnecessary packages), to minimize the file size?

Is flutter build web all you do to build a release version? Is there anything else that should be done other than flutter clean?